# Array indexing inconsistent between script and console Python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy

I am setting up a 3D box, 2x2x3 in this example. I have used a list comprehension to set up the coordinates of the centroids of each 1x1x1 cell in the box (I am using Python 2.7). I then convert that list structure into a numpy array and want to randomly half fill the box.

```
import numpy as np

tube = []

xy = 2
for z in range(3):
    tube.append([(x+0.5, y+0.5, z+0.5, 0) for x in range(xy) for y in range(xy)])            

centroid = np.array(tube)

exitFlag = False

for numParticle in range(6):

    while exitFlag == False:

        zCoord = np.random.randint(3, size=1)
        xyCoord = np.random.randint((xy*xy), size=1)
        print zCoord, xyCoord

        if centroid[zCoord][xyCoord][3] == 0.0:
            centroid[zCoord][xyCoord][3] = 1.0
            exitFlag = True


print centroid
```

I am happy with the shape of the array but I get the following error,

```
  if centroid[zCoord][xyCoord][3] == 0.0:
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Now if I query the exact same entry in the console I get no index error.

For example if the randint calls return 0 and 3 respectively, I get the above error.

Yet when I check enter `centroid[0][3][3]` into the console I get `0.0`, which is what I expect.

Why is the script swapping my indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`centroid[zCoord][xyCoord][3]` is not a good way to index an array.  Sometimes it works, but it isn't the intended mechanism.

One set of brackets gives more control:

```
    if centroid[zCoord, xyCoord, 3] == 0:
        centroid[zCoord, xyCoord, 3] = 1
        exitFlag=True
```

I added

```
    print centroid[zCoord].shape
    print centroid[zCoord][xyCoord]
```

and got `(1, 4, 4)` followed by the error message.  `ZCoord` as you generate it isn't a scalar, but an array of shape `(1,)`.  So indexing with it leaves that initial `1` dimension.  The 2nd bracket then tries to index on that dimension, rather than the 2nd that you expect.  The reason your console tests work is that you using scalars, not arrays.

Comment: Ahhh OK so when I leave out the 'size' parameter in the randinit call it returns a scalar & it works. Thanks its all making sense again.